# How to prevent users to add entries for a given time using ASP NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this scenario:

> Add a product but block adding for 1 minute for other users. After 1 min they can normally add one.
>
> Adding a product it is not blocked for the user itself who added it
> but for others.

I have this and it is working like a charm:

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> AddProducts(string citaId, string paciente, string medico, string modalidad)
 {
    var usuario = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserName();

                if (Session["User"] != null)
                {
                    if(Session["User"].ToString() != usuario)
                    {
                        var med = await _context.MEDICOS.FindAsync(medico);

                        var objetoerrr1 = new
                        {
                            type = "error",
                            message = $"you cannot add a product, WAIT 1 MIN."
                        };

                        return Json(objetoerrr1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    
                }

... the rest of the code for adding a product

// create a session
Session["User"] = usuario;
Session.Timeout = 1;
```

But my problem is that it is not working when using different browsers or PCs and It is like session is empty in different devices.

Well I have never worked with sessions in `ASP NET MVC5` before so when I heard this requeriment, sessions came to my mind so I used them.

How can I achieve such thing? Should I use database to store the session or something? Or should not I be using sessions for this approach?

Comment: Session is completely the wrong approach here. It's used to store data on the server associated with a specific browser on a specific computer. Opening a different browser, or using a different computer, will use a different session. If the user clears their cookies, they will also get a new session. [ASP.NET Session State Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581(v=vs.100))

Comment: Yes, you'll need some sort of persistent storage on the server side to store when a product is added and perform Authorization from that information.

Comment: That is right it is about concurrency, but client asked for this approach like blocking it for a given time.

Comment: Assuming you've got your user authentication/authorization done properly, I _suspect_ your task is really about [concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Answer (score 1):

You should save the sessions into database, not only for this, also for security reasons. And give that session an unique identifier (and save it inside the cookie and retrieve and check it everytime) in order to know login timestamp, logout timestamp, prevent cookie-copy between browsers, prevent cookie-copy after log out, prevent browser-copy, duplicated sessions, if roles changes meanwhile the user is logged in, etc.

Of course there are a lot of ways to do this without database, but this is my answer. I use only database for this because I save user logins into database, as their roles.